# how to achieve like sumifs function in panda dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

I want to add a column to calculate the cumulative uptime.
Below is my dataframe:

[image: original dataframe]

What I expect is like below:

```
body_id    active_date  uptime cumulative_uptime
51C00195    2017/1/26   1.18   1.18
51C00232    2017/1/12   0.83   0.83
51C00232    2017/1/19   6.28   7.11
51C00232    2017/1/20   9.35   16.46
51C00232    2017/1/21   3.88   20.34
```

Above calculation could be simply achieved in excel using `sumif`,
however in `pandas`, I have no idea how to do it.

Could anyone help? Thanks in advance~~

Comment: What is your criteria?

Comment: For cumulative sums there is a `cumsum` function available in pandas. Can you provide your input data as text?

Comment: What does mean uptime 1.18 or cumulative_uptime equal to 0.83. Is it in days? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want the uptime to be added up.

Answer (score 0):

I think cumsum works for it

```
df['cumulative_uptime'] = df.groupby('body_id')['uptime'].cumsum()

>>> import pandas as pd
>>>     
... df = pd.DataFrame({'body_id': ['51C00195','51C00232', '51C00232','51C00232','51C00232'],
...     'active_date': ['2017/1/26','2017/1/12','2017/1/19','2017/1/20','2017/1/21'],
...                    'uptime': [1.18,0.83,6.28,9.35,3.88]
...                        })
>>> 
>>> df['cumulative_uptime'] = df.groupby('body_id')['uptime'].cumsum()
>>> 
>>> df
  active_date   body_id  uptime  cumulative_uptime
0   2017/1/26  51C00195    1.18               1.18
1   2017/1/12  51C00232    0.83               0.83
2   2017/1/19  51C00232    6.28               7.11
3   2017/1/20  51C00232    9.35              16.46
4   2017/1/21  51C00232    3.88              20.34
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what I want is to have a cumulative value for each row, instead of only one value for each id.

Comment: I think it covers. It has a cumulative value for each row